# xcode/iphone custom class xml parcer

Tags: iphone, xml

I have a custom class and I set specific properties of that class based on the xml node name coming in.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"strap"])
{
    parcelObj.strap = nodeContent;        
}

else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"owner"])
{
    parcelObj.owner=nodeContent;

}
```

etc. etc...

I wanna know if I can lose the else if's all together and do this (somehow)

parcelObj."elementName" = nodeContent;

Make sense? I am not sure how to pass the "elementName" as the property ya know?

Comment: There might be a way using pre-processor directives to append the two pieces of information together. My knowledge of directives is limited though, so I'll not suggest any solutions but I will suggest that you look to those if no other solution is possible

Comment: Ziggizworth, what do you mean, sry kinda newbie...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more info then you are looking for, but check out my custom xml parser [`JHXMLParser`](http://pastebin.com/qemCGXAm) class.  It parses an xml file and creates an array of dictionaries.  Each dictionary has the xml tags name as a key for the text value inside the tag.  So, if the xml data looked like this:

```
<PHOTOS>
    <PHOTO>
        <ID>177</ID>
        <THUMB><![CDATA[http://www.blah.com/thumbs/489650795.jpg]]></THUMB>
        <IMAGE><![CDATA[http://www.blah.com/images/489650795.jpg]]></IMAGE>
    </PHOTO>
    <PHOTO>
        <ID>178</ID>
        <THUMB><![CDATA[http://www.blah.com/thumbs/489650798.jpg]]></THUMB>
        <IMAGE><![CDATA[http://www.blah.com/images/489650798.jpg]]></IMAGE>
    </PHOTO>
</PHOTOS>
```

It would create an array with 2 dictionary elements.  The first dictionary would have 3 keys ("ID", "THUMB", "IMAGE") and 3 values ("117", "http://www.blah.com/thumbs/489650795.jpg", and "http://www.blah.com/images/489650795.jpg") respectively.

Here are the important methods (`_key`, `_previousTag`, `_currentTag`, `_elementText`, and `_parsedData` are ivars and `_key` is a string that would be `@"PHOTO"` for the above XML):

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    _parsedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    _currentTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:elementName];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:_key]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_parsedData addObject:tmpDict];
        [tmpDict release];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if ([_previousTag isEqualToString:_currentTag]) {
        [_elementText appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    } else {
        _elementText = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    }
    if (![_previousTag isEqualToString:_currentTag]) {
        _previousTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:_currentTag];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([_previousTag isEqualToString:elementName]) {
        [[_parsedData lastObject] setObject:_elementText forKey:elementName];
    } else {
        _previousTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
    }
}
```